# iOS push notifications feedback service

Tags: php, ios

I can send to my swift 2 app push notifications via PHP.
now I would like to have a script for the feedback service.

I found this:

```
$ctx = stream_context_create();
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', 'xxx.pem');
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'verify_peer', false);

$fp = stream_socket_client('ssl://feedback.push.apple.com:2196', $error, $errorString, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, $ctx);

if (!$fp) {
 echo "Failed to connect feedback server:".$err.". ".$errstr."<br />";
 exit();
}
else {
 echo "Connection to feedback server OK<br />";
}

 echo "APNS feedback results<br />";
 while ($devcon = fread($fp, 38))
 {
 $arr = unpack("H*", $devcon);
 $rawhex = trim(implode("", $arr));
 $feedbackTime = hexdec(substr($rawhex, 0, 8));
 $feedbackDate = date('Y-m-d H:i', $feedbackTime);
 $feedbackLen = hexdec(substr($rawhex, 8, 4));
 $feedbackDeviceToken = substr($rawhex, 12, 64);
 echo "TIMESTAMP:" . $feedbackDate . "<br />";
 echo "DEVICE ID:" . $feedbackDeviceToken. "<br /><br />";
 }
fclose($fp);
```

This code shows me that:

```
Connection to feedback server OK
APNS feedback results
```

But no result. I sent a few minutes ago and push notification to a token 0. this is an invalid token.

But why I didn't get this invalid token via feedback service?

Answer (score 0):

You only get results when there is something to show. Results are shown one time, after that it is deleted so you should handle it immediatly when received